# how to link up two forms

Tags: wpf, vb.net

One form to control the simulation. 
 One form to represent the stained glass window.

i have a `NumericUpDown1` which contains a list of numbers i would like to draw Lines with to show on my `SecondForm` but when i try and run the program nothing shows
This is how i coded

```
    Dim Redpen As New Pen(Color.Red)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyGraphicsClass As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    a = 0
    b = 20
    c = 30
    d = 50
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

    NumericUpDown1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None
    NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 7
    NumericUpDown1.Minimum = 1
    Controls.Add(NumericUpDown1)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SecondForm.Show()
    If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 1 Then
        MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, b, a, b)
    End If

    Number_Of_Lines = 2
    For i = 1 Number_Of_Lines Step 1
        If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2 Then
            MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, c, a, c)
        End If
    Next i

    Number_Of_Lines = 3
    For i = 1 Number_Of_Lines Step 1
        If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 3 Then
            MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, d, a, d)
        End If
    Next i

    Number_Of_Lines = 4
    For i = 1 Number_Of_Lines Step 1
        If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 4 Then
            MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, c, a, c)
        End If
    Next i

    Number_Of_Lines = 5
    For i = 1 Number_Of_Lines Step 1
        If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 5 Then
            MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, b, a, b)
        End If
    Next i

    Number_Of_Lines = 6
    For i = 1 Number_Of_Lines Step 1
        If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 6 Then
            MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, c, a, c)
        End If
    Next i

    Number_Of_Lines = 7
    For i = 1 Number_Of_Lines Step 1
        If NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 7 Then
            MyGraphicsClass.DrawLine(Pens.Red, a, c, a, c)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: In order to ask questions on SO, you must have a basic understanding of what you are asking for. We are not here to teach you from the beginning, we are here to help you when you get stuck on something particular. Please show us some code.

Comment: i edited my post hope its we explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Not sure what you are doing in you're `NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged` code. You're setting the min/max everytime the value changes, and then re-adding it to the controls collection???

Second, I cannot see how or where your `SecondForm` is declared/initialized or what `MyGraphicsClass` is, which I believe are the 2 main pieces needed to answer your question but, here is what I know about what you are trying to do.

Because you need to draw your lines in the `paint` event of the second form, you need to be able to read the values from your first form. The best way to do this is to assign the instance of the first form to a variable in the second form. (there are many different ways to do this. Public variable is the easiest) Then in the paint event of the second form, you can read the values for the controls of the first form. You will want to keep the instance of the second form, in the first form as well, so that you can tell the second form to repaint, when you need to.

--First form variables

```
Private _SecondForm as SecondForm
```

--When you show the second form for the first time, something like this:

```
If _SecondForm is nothing then
  _SecondForm = new SecondForm
  _SecondForm.MyFirstForm = me
End If
_SecondForm.show(me) 'You could also do this which sets the owner, then you can ask for the owner in the second form, instead of setting a variable.
```

Now you have in instance of the second form that you can use anytime in your first form.

--Second Form Variables, notice this was set in the first form (above)

```
Public MyFirstForm as FirstForm
```

--In your Paint event

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, MyFirstForm.NumericUpDown1.Value, MyFirstForm.NumericUpDown2.Value, MyFirstForm.NumericUpDown3.Value, MyFirstForm.NumericUpDown4.Value)
```

Or, if you are using the owner method, you can do this:

```
Dim x As FirstForm = Me.Owner
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, x.NumericUpDown1.Value, x.NumericUpDown2.Value, x.NumericUpDown3.Value, x.NumericUpDown4.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

some_variable = firstform.NumericUpdown.YourObjectHere